# How to delete files in android 10 and above

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, file-permissions, android-file

I have to delete a particular file (screenshot image) when a certain event happens and for that I used the below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But now its only working till android 9 because of the following

> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE no longer provides write access when targeting
> Android 11+, even when using requestLegacyExternalStorage

It says even when using requestLegacyExternalStorage.

**Then what is the alternative for this problem?**

And this is my code btw

```
File fdelete = new File(path);
        if (fdelete.exists()) {
            if (fdelete.delete()) {
                getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(path))));
                Log.i(TAG, "deleteTheFile: file deleted");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "deleteTheFile: file not dellleeettteeeddd");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please start with putting a value for path in your code. Not every path is the same. And you did not even tell if your code works.